# Opening Files In Python Error

Tags: python

When opening files in python, I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is

```
p=open("afile.txt","r")
file=p.read()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UnicodeError. You are trying to read a Unicode character in with the ASCII codec.

Try:

```
import codecs

p = codecs.open("afile.txt", "r", "utf-8")
f = p.read()
```

or

```
import codecs

p = codecs.open("afile.txt", "r", "utf-16")
f = p.read()
```

You should also probably consider using:

```
with codecs.open("afile.txt", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    # Do whatever you want with f
```

This makes it able to auto-close the file when you exit the `with` statement.

You could also try `iso-8859-15` or `cp437` Take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet and https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open.

Comment: When I use this I get TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: @MaxCoates try it now. Updated to use the codecs package